# Linq parametrizable group by with 2 properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm trying to do a LinQ request with a group by where a parameter is parametrizable by an Expression ( `(Expression<Func<CompanyModel,TKey>> myGroupingProperty`) and the other one is hard coded. But even if my code compile I get an error that linq does not support lambdas. Would you have any idea how to do this request?

Here is the code sample:

```
public List<timelineResult> getTimelinebyCompany<TKey>(Expression<Func<CompanyModel,TKey>> myGroupingProperty, Filter item)
{
    int cntToBeSureThatTheQueryExecuteAtLeastOneTime = 0;
    List<timelineResult> toto = new List<timelineResult>();
    using (var db = new fintechDbContext())
    {         
        while (cntToBeSureThatTheQueryExecuteAtLeastOneTime == 0)
        {
             toto = (from p in db.companyDBSET                                    
                     select p).GroupBy(p=> new {p.Founded_Year, myGroupingProperty})
                             .Select(o => new timelineResult{ year = o.Key.Founded_Year, cluster = o.myGroupingProperty.ToString(), count = o.Count() })
                             .OrderBy(o => o.year).ToList();
            cntToBeSureThatTheQueryExecuteAtLeastOneTime++;
        }
    }

    return toto;
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the error message?

Comment: It would also be helpful to provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet.

Comment: This can't work, you're using in a lambda, you're trying to do something like: `p=> new {p.Founded_Year, p2 => p2.PropertyToGroupBy}` with nested lambdas. You'll probably have to use expression trees to do this, or provide the full `p=> new {p.Founded_Year, myGroupingProperty}` as parameter instead of just one part of the key (creating a class/struct so you don't have to work with an anonymous type for the key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeking for is doable, but not the way you tried because the passed  lambda expression cannot be used directly inside another lambda expression.

You should start first by creating a generic class to hold the grouping key. It's similar to system provided `Tuple`, but has parameterless constructor and simple property get/setters to conform to the EF projection rules:

```
public class GroupKey<K1, K2>
{
    public K1 Key1 { get; set; }
    public K2 Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to build dynamically lambda expression like this

```
Expression<Func<T, K1, K2>> keySelector = x => 
    new GroupKey<K1, K2> { Key1 = x.Prop1, Key2 = x.Prop2 };
```

In order to do that, you'll need some `Expression` helpers:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

and you can encapsulate the grouping part in a custom extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<GroupKey<K1, K2>, T>> GroupByPair<T, K1, K2>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, K1>> keySelector1, Expression<Func<T, K2>> keySelector2)
    {
        var parameter = keySelector1.Parameters[0];
        var key1 = keySelector1.Body;
        var key2 = keySelector2.Body.ReplaceParameter(keySelector2.Parameters[0], parameter);
        var keyType = typeof(GroupKey<K1, K2>);
        var keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, GroupKey<K1, K2>>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(keyType),
                Expression.Bind(keyType.GetProperty("Key1"), key1),
                Expression.Bind(keyType.GetProperty("Key2"), key2)),
            parameter);
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

Finally, the essential part of your method becomes like this:

```
toto = db.companyDBSET                                    
    .GroupByPair(p => p.Founded_Year, myGroupingProperty)
    .Select(g => new timelineResult
    { 
        year = g.Key.Key1,
        cluster = g.Key.Key2.ToString(),
        count = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.year)
    .ToList();
```